# COUNTIFS to get a percentage when there are blank values

Tags: excel, countif

I have a set of data for quarterly feedback from students. Sem1, Sem2, Sem3, Sem4 (semester 1,2,3,4). They can write excellent, good, satisfactory and poor as their response for each lecture. Sometimes, they leave the response for some lectures blank.

Say I have 100 responses, 25 from each semester, on 10 lectures. Column A is which semester, column B lecture 1, column c lecture 2, etc to lecture 10. So cell B2:excellent, B3:good, B4:good (all for lecture 1).

If they don't leave any responses blank I can use COUNTIFS to get the percentage of 'excellent's, 'good's etc received for each lecture: countifs(if column a contains Sem1, count how many instances of 'excellent' are in the total range in column b, divided by the count of Sem1 in column a).

E.g. How many 'excellent's there are for lecture 1 (column b) in semester 1:
`=SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A100,"Sem1",B2:B100,"Excellent"))/COUNTIF(A2:A100,"Sem1")`

This is fine until they leave anything blank in column B because then to get the percentage I'm dividing by a higher number than there are answers in column B.

If I have 25 responses for sem1, 10 of these are excellent but two are blank, it would be 10/25 (40%) instead of 10/23 (43%). It would be fine if there was only one lecture but there are multiple lectures/columns and students responded about some but not all lectures. How can I adapt my function to take this into account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply should devide by all non-blank cells for semester one. To do so use the following formula:

`=COUNTIFS(A2:A100,"Sem1",B2:B100,"Excellent")/COUNTIFS(A2:A100,"Sem1",B2:B100,"<>"&"")`

I also removed your `SUM` around your `COUNTIFS` since `COUNTIFS` already returns an aggregation, or did you have a special need for that?

Comment: Amazing! That works perfectly, thanks so much! No, I think I put the SUM in as overkill...

Comment: Happy to help. If answers are usefull to you please let the community know by voting and/or accepting an answer.